# How to measure the speed of a kivy app

Tags: kivy

How can I measure the speed of a certain code in my kivy program?

I've got a function, that adds ten screens by using a dict, pictures and screenmanager, and that takes more then 5 seconds. I would like to find out, what is the slowest part of this function.

`line_profiler` ([described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677606/how-to-measure-the-speed-of-a-python-function)) sounds good, but if I run it, my application window stays black, no widgets are drawed and so I couldn't click on some buttons.

Which are the best methods?

Answer (score 0):

Try **cProfile** - it will dump all the functions calls with times to a file to review later on...

```
import cProfile

class MyApp(App):
    def on_start(self):
        self.profile = cProfile.Profile()
        self.profile.enable()

    def on_stop(self):
        self.profile.disable()
        self.profile.dump_stats('myapp.profile')
```

see also [How can I profile a Kivy application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960989/how-can-i-profile-a-kivy-application/36966126#36966126)

That said... if you have a **guess** on which part is the **slowest** you can always put some **time.time()** prints to figure what exactly causes the slow-down